# firestore display values of data in php

Tags: php, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

**how to display each record's values?**

```
$collectionReference = $this->fsdb->collection('orders');
$documentReference = $collectionReference->document('MSKpcuedwxNmdLn2Ydsp');
$snapshot = $documentReference->snapshot();

echo "Hello " . $snapshot['userId'];
```

I am receiving this error:

**ErrorException
Object of class Google\Cloud\Firestore\DocumentReference could not be converted to string**

`print_r()` function works correctly but how to access each individual record?

I have been searching for hours to get this solved but I found no reference on web

Please help me in here...

Answer (score 0):

A snapshot contains both data and metadata about the document. To get the data you need to call its `data()` method:

```
$collectionReference = $this->fsdb->collection('orders');
$documentReference = $collectionReference->document('MSKpcuedwxNmdLn2Ydsp');
$snapshot = $documentReference->snapshot();

if ($snapshot->exists()) {
    printf('Document data:' . PHP_EOL);
    echo "Hello " . $snapshot->data()['userId'];
} else {
    printf('Document %s does not exist!' . PHP_EOL, $snapshot->id());
}
```

Also see the Firebase documentation on [getting a document from Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document).

Comment: Now this code gives this error.... ParseError: 
**syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ',' or ';'**

Comment: Yeah, that probably should be `->`. Updated my answer.

Comment: Yes i corrected that but it gives now **Object of class Google\Cloud\Firestore\DocumentReference could not be converted to string** this error